# Getting java.lang.ExceptionInIntiliazerError in Android

Tags: java, android, api, owl

I'm very new to Android programming and I'm trying to write an Android app that would parse an OWL file (.owl file) and display the classes and subclasses. When ever the user clicks the button, the file is read from the **assets** folder of the Eclipse Project, the OWL file is parsed and the names of the classes are printed on to the console.

But whenever I click the button, the emulator crashes throwing the following exceptions:

```
02-23 16:49:36.430: E/AndroidRuntime(597): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 16:49:36.430: E/AndroidRuntime(597): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
02-23 16:49:36.430: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at com.Sample.SampleApp.StartingPoint.parseOWLFile(StartingPoint.java:105)
02-23 16:49:36.430: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at com.Sample.SampleApp.StartingPoint$3.onClick(StartingPoint.java:68)
```

Here is my the Java code I wrote:

```
public class StartingPoint extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final int REQUEST_PATH = 1;
String currentFile;
EditText et1;
Button browse, ok, exit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    browse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.browseButton);
    browse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            getfile(v);
        }

    });

    exit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ExitButton);
    exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });

    ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.OKButton);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            parseOWLFile();
        }

    });
}

public void getfile(View view)
{
    Intent i1 = new Intent(this, FileChooser.class);
    startActivityForResult(i1, REQUEST_PATH);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_PATH)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            currentFile = data.getStringExtra("GetFileName");
            et1.setText(currentFile);
        }
    }
}

public void parseOWLFile()
{
    //String file = et1.getText().toString(); //Uncomment this when using on phone/tablet

    String file = "antibiotics.owl";

    try
    {
        //System.out.println("File name is "+file);

        //File f = new File(file);
        InputStream fis = getAssets().open(file);

        OntModel base = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM );
        base.read(fis, null);

        String ns = base.getNsPrefixURI("Ontology");

        Resource r = base.getResource(ns+" Concept");
        OntClass theClass = r.as(OntClass.class);

        Individual indiv = base.createIndividual(ns+"IndivTest", theClass);

        for (Iterator<Resource> i = indiv.listRDFTypes(true); i.hasNext(); )
            System.out.println( indiv.getURI() + " is asserted in class " + i.next() );

        OntModel inf = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF, base );

        Individual ind = inf.getIndividual( ns + "indivTest" );
        for (Iterator<Resource> i = ind.listRDFTypes(true); i.hasNext(); )
            System.out.println( ind.getURI() + " is inferred to be in class " + i.next() );
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

I have imported the AndroJena 0.5 version jars into my Eclipse Project.

Here are some more exceptions that I got:

```
02-23 16:49:36.430: E/AndroidRuntime(597): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
02-23 16:49:36.430: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec.<clinit>(OntModelSpec.java:54)
02-23 16:49:36.430: E/AndroidRuntime(597): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
02-23 16:49:36.430: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.ProfileRegistry.<clinit>(ProfileRegistry.java:48)
02-23 16:49:36.430: E/AndroidRuntime(597): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
02-23 16:49:36.430: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(ModelFactory.java:122)
02-23 16:49:36.430: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(ModelFactory.java:116)
```

### Update

Here's the updated stack trace:

```
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.XMLHandler.<init>(XMLHandler.java:367)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.RDFXMLParser.<init>(RDFXMLParser.java:52)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.RDFXMLParser.create(RDFXMLParser.java:85)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.JenaReader.<init>(JenaReader.java:62)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.RDFReaderFImpl.getReader(RDFReaderFImpl.java:114)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:220)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntDocumentManager.findMetadata(OntDocumentManager.java:895)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntDocumentManager.initialiseMetadata(OntDocumentManager.java:853)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntDocumentManager.<init>(OntDocumentManager.java:201)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntDocumentManager.<init>(OntDocumentManager.java:183)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntDocumentManager.<init>(OntDocumentManager.java:167)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntDocumentManager.getInstance(OntDocumentManager.java:245)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec.getDocumentManager(OntModelSpec.java:340)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntModelImpl.getDocumentManager(OntModelImpl.java:181)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntModelImpl.loadImports(OntModelImpl.java:1887)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntModelImpl.<init>(OntModelImpl.java:148)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntModelImpl.<init>(OntModelImpl.java:128)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(ModelFactory.java:410)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.Sample.SampleApp.StartingPoint.parseOWLFile(StartingPoint.java:105)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.Sample.SampleApp.StartingPoint$3.onClick(StartingPoint.java:68)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.hp.hpl.jena.iri.IRIFactory
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.ARPOptions.<clinit>(ARPOptions.java:60)
02-24 21:29:24.273: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  ... 33 more
```

How can I eliminate this exception and get to parse the OWL file?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html

Comment: @Nambari But, I'm not using any **static** variable in my code.

Comment: You are not, but the code at StartingPoint.java:105 does.

Comment: Ok. So how do I eliminate it? All the examples on the Internet that tell how to parse an OWL file use that line of code. :/

Comment: I think your Android version is not supportive (or) you have incompatible version of jars in classpath. You need to figure out which one of these could be causing the issue.

Comment: There is only one version of AndroJena. That is 0.5 version.

Comment: I am sorry! I never used it on Android. Based on exception, it is evident that some dependency issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc for this exception says:

> Signals that an unexpected exception has occurred in a static initializer. An ExceptionInInitializerError is thrown to indicate that an exception occurred during evaluation of a static initializer or the initializer for a static variable.

You then say:

> But, I'm not using any static variable in my code.

However, your code >>is<< triggering static initialization of some class, and that static initialization is throwing an unchecked exception which is not being caught.

Normally, the stacktrace of the `ExceptionInInitializerError` would include the traces of the unchecked exception that caused the problem.  I don't see this in the fragments of stacktrace that you have included ... but I expect that it is in the complete stacktrace.

If you want further help, provide the **complete unedited** stacktrace rather than random fragments of one or more stacktraces.

---

**UPDATE**

The salient part of the stacktrace is at the end:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
  at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.Metadata.<clinit>(Metadata.java:26)
  ... 21 more
```

The JVM has been unable to load (or possibly initialize) the `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` class.  The problem is most likely that the SLF4J jar file is missing.

The dependencies of that version of Jena should be explained in the documentation.

Comment: I've included the latest **slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar** in the Project's build path and I get a new exception: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**

Comment: Identify the JAR file that defines `com.hp.hpl.jena.iri.IRIFactory` and include that as well.  And consider using a build tool that understands dependencies.